# Can an externally created XML file included in the plist of a project (in xcode)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an external valid XML file. Can I simply save it in the Xcode project folder to make it available as a plist?

Comment: Most XML files are not plists.  Is it really a plist?

Comment: plist xml is harder to read than normal xml. Are you converting normal xml to plist and want to save it ? or you want to save raw external valid xml as xml file and save it into resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether its plist or xml you can drag and drop in your XCode project resources folder (its common place where we save application resources like property list files, xml files,images). You can read file using:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"Plist Contents: %@",tempDict);
[tempDict release];
```

If its an xml

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData* xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if(xmlData)
{
 NSString* xmlDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"XML file Contents:%@",xmlDataString);
 [xmlDataString release];
}
```

If you are looking to parse XML using NSXMLParser you can give that file to NSXMLParser to load and parse. `initWithContentsOfURL:` method

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie. I was trying to develop a property list via xcode that would be used to load some arrays. I found the preparation of the plist via the xcode screen pretty tedious. So I thought that I could simply create a text file to enter the data. If that is possible, then I can use my many other xml files without doing the tedious data entry in xcode.

Comment: Although PLIST is made up using XML we often refer both of these as different formats. plist data entry is not so tedious as XML unless you are typing all key value xml elements by yourself. You have a plist editor on Mac that you can use which has same affect as editing plist in XCode I don't find it tedious. If all you want to do is parse XML files then why convert them to plist in first place where you can use easy to use NSXMLParser to parse them.